# How can I set custom validation error messages from a controller, in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a registration form with Laravel 8 and Sanctum.

I have this piece of code in the **AuthController** to validate the form fields:

```
public function register(Request $request) {
    $fields = $request->validate([
        'first_name' => 'required|string,',
        'last_name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|string|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|string|confirmed',
        'accept' => 'accepted',
    ]);

    // More code here

}
```

I want to display more user-friendly validation error messages.

Rather than changing the `validation.php` file (*resources\lang\en\validation.php*), I want to change the set them for the registration form only, in the method above.

##### The problem

As someone that has used Codeigniter for a long time, I had, in Codeigniter, the posibility to do just that:

```
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'required', array('required' => 'The "First name" field is required'));
```

I was unable to do something similar in Laravel 8.

###### How do I get the desired result in Laravel 8?

Comment: You can optionally supply messages as the second argument, and optionally set attributes in the third argument. This is the facade method:

`\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator make(array $data, array $rules, array $messages = [], array $customAttributes = [])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can work for ya.

```
    $rules = [
        'first_name' => 'required|string,',
        'last_name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|string|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|string|confirmed',
        'accept' => 'accepted'
    ];

    $customMessages = [
        'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

Also check out the [laravel customizing error messages documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages).

Comment: How do I target each/any field with a custom message? Like, for instance, "Looks like you forgot to tell us your name".

Comment: It would be better for you if you find it by yourself, but I'll give it to ya: `'first_name.required' => 'Looks like you forgot to tell us your name'`

Answer (score 1):

The validate function excepts 3 parameters. A)  request, B) the  rules, C)  Custome Messages.

`$this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);` It means define your custom Message Array by key value. Key is the rulename like require. For example:

```php
[
    'required' => 'The :attribute is really,really, really required if you use Login!'
    'email.required' => 'Without email you dont come in ;-)'
]
```